# How do I know where logging messages comes from in Log4j2 framework?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I am writing logging configuration in Log4j2.xml.I have configured AppenderRef in specified package.

```
<Logger name="org.springframework.boot" level="info" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
           <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
</Logger>
```

How do i know where the message comes from.
For instance.
When I get some messages in "org.springframework.boot", all I need to know are the msg and the specified package.

1,message "....."

2,package "org.springframework.boot"

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Did you check this web page ? [link](https://mkyong.com/logging/log4j2-xml-example/)

Answer (score 1):

Every log event can include the location information of the caller. The different Layouts may or may not include it as it is somewhat expensive to include. In the pattern layout you would include it by specifying the %class, %method, and %line conversion patterns.

Answer (score 0):

@rgoers' answer is right, so I'll just be a bit more specific here and add some source:

The [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html) (scroll down to *Patterns*) describes how to solve your issue:
[image: documentation of log4j2 - how to output the fully qualified class name of the caller issuing the logging request]
You can `output the **fully qualified** class name of the caller issuing the logging request`. That should help to determine, where the logging call came from.

Please also be aware that the patterns are case-sensitive, so there's a difference between `c{precision}` and `C{precision}`,